# Вызов метода класса-собственника в классе-потомке

Tags: c#, .net

И так, загуглить вопрос не получилось, так как не смог сформулировать вопрос. А то, что в заголовке, это полная мура.

Имеем некий класс с неким методом, который вызывается по тику таймера `timer`:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    Timer timer;
    public SomeClass()
    {
         timer = new Timer(100);
         timer.Tick += SomeMethod
         timer.Start();
    }  
    public void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
         //bla-bla
         //Здесь вызвать!!!
    }   
}
```

Имеем другой класс с некоторым методом и полем типа 'SomeClass':

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    SomeClass someField;
    public AnotherClass()
    { 
         someField = new SomeClass(); 
    } 

    public int AnotherMethod()
    {
         //bla-bla
         return 1;
    }   
}
```

Эти два класса не связаны наследованием.

Как видно из кода, метод `SomeMethod` вызывается по тику таймера.

Вопрос: как вызвать метод `AnotherMethod` класса `AnotherClass` в методе `SomeMethod` класса `SomeClass`?

Знаю два способа:

1. создать событие и дергать его в `SomeMethod`,
2. передать ссылку на объект `AnotherClass` с помощью `this` в конструкторе `SomeClass` и присвоить ссылку полю `SomeClass`.

Корректны ли такие способы и вообще такие вызовы с точки зрения требований "хорошего кода"? Какие еще способы есть?

Comment: Почему AnotherClass владеет ссылкой на SomeClass, а не наоборот?

Comment: Так надо. AnotherClass представляет, что-то вроде `ViewModel` и объединяет несколько разношерстных объектов типа `SomeClass`.

Comment: В текущем дизайне — никак. `AnotherClass` ничего не знает о том, что происходит внутри `SomeClass`. Если нужно — либо заинжектируйте ссылку на `AnotherClass`, либо выставьте event в `SomeClass`, чтобы `AnotherClass` мог подписаться. Какой из данных путей правильный — непонятно, пока вы не расскажете о смысле ваших классов.

Comment: @VladD В приницпе, так я и предполагал. Спасибо, такого ответа мне пока достаточно

Comment: Можете в SomeClass создать делегат который по умолчанию будет иметь значение функции класса SomeClass. А в классе Another Class переприсвойте его.